# extjs dataview not loading data store

Tags: dataview, extjs3

I'm baffled that this dataView is empty!  I have this same setup working with images but it's not displaying here. Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

json:

```
{rows:[{"noteid":"4","txid":"97","contactid":"38","displayname":"Jeb Hafkin","txdate":"08\/20\/2010","date":"12\/08\/2011","type":"Treatment Note","content":"new test<img src=\"..\/logos\/1912323619.jpg\">","subject":"Jeb's note","firstname":"Jeb","lastname":"Hafkin"},{"noteid":"6","txid":"0","contactid":"51","displayname":"Bill Hyyman","txdate":null,"date":"12\/12\/2011","type":"","content":"test","subject":"","firstname":"Bill","lastname":"Hyyman"}], "success": true}
```

data Store, tpl, dataview:

```
var noteStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['noteid','txid','contactid', 'displayname', 'date', 
            'subject','txdate','type','amtpd','content' ],
        root: 'rows',
        id: 'noteid'
    }),
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '/request.php?x=noteStore'
    })
});
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate (
    '<tpl for ".">',
         '<p class="note">noteid = {noteid} </p>',
    '</tpl>'
);
var noteDataView = new Ext.DataView({
        store: noteStore,
        tpl: tpl,
        autoHeight:true,
        multiSelect: true,
        overClass:'x-view-over',
        itemSelector:'p.note',
        emptyText: 'No notes to display'
});
var notePanel  = new Ext.Panel ({
    layout: 'fit',
    padding: 10,
    items: [noteDataView],
    tbar: noteTb
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The store needs to be loaded. Try adding autoLoad: true to your store:

```
var noteStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['noteid','txid','contactid', 'displayname', 'date', 
            'subject','txdate','type','amtpd','content' ],
        root: 'rows',
        id: 'noteid',
    }),
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '/request.php?x=noteStore'
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});
```